# Importing product names with special characters using Magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, magmi, character-encoding, utf-8

I am trying to import products using Magmi.

Some of the products include special characters, such as é, à, etc.

When I import the products, I get the following error for the items that have the special characters:

> SKU [the product's sku] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '[character code]' for column 'value' at row [column # I use for the product name]

So far I have tried:

- Encodings: UTF-8 and Latin1 when I export to csv
- Change the special characters to Latin1 values

I keep getting the same error, whatever I try to change.

Please help me :)

Comment: What application are you using to save the CSV file?

Comment: Microsoft Excel (Office 365)

Comment: Try saving it through Libre Office Calc with UTF-8 and try import again. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment as answer, to not leave it unanswered:

> Try saving it through Libre Office Calc with UTF-8 and try import again. Let me know if it helped.

Excel is not very good at character encoding and even worse at CSV files in general because it intepretes the "C" in CSV as "Semicolon" instead of "Comma".

So for CSV manipulation, LibreOffice Calc is always a better choice.