# Magmi Special charactars not allowing to upload

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

I am facing an issue when uploading Products with Magmi only when excel sheet contains  **special charactar**s so, I followed [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/importing-product-names-with-special-characters-using-magmi) & tried saving with `Libre Office Calc with UTF-8', but that didn't work for me.

[image]

Or is I need to change in Database to accept **utf8mb4** instead of **UTF-8** to accept special characters as mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magmi dont accept very very high special charactars as below :

**° , ™ , ±**  [ examples : 108°, WIRE™ , ±0.5% ] , once we removed those, it worked fine....